# jQuery slideDown on nested table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to make the nested table to slide down from top when a user clicks "Show" button. But jQuery's `slideDown()` function instantly shows the table even with 500ms animation duration, which is not what I want. Where did I make a mistake? I'm using jQuery 3.4.1 and a Bootstrap 4.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.show-me', function (e) {
    var elem = $(this);
    var target_id = $(this).data('show');
    var elements = $(target_id);
    if ($(this)[0].classList.contains('collapsed')) {
            e.preventDefault();
        elements.slideUp(500);
        $(this).removeClass('collapsed');
    } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        elements.slideDown(500);
        $(this).addClass('collapsed');
    }
 })
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: None;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Date of Birth</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Show</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Josh</td>
    <td>Rose</td>
    <td>09.04.1995</td>
    <td>USA</td>
    <td data-show=".show_1" class="show-me">Show</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="hidden show_1">
    <td colspan=99>
      <table class="w-100">
        <tr>
          <th>Mobile number</th>
          <th>Provider</th>
          <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
          <td>999 999 999</td>
          <td>XYZ</td>
          <td>1274</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>888 888 888</td>
          <td>XYZ</td>
          <td>1111</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Sabine</td>
    <td>Perr</td>
    <td>15.06.1988</td>
    <td>Finland</td>
    <td data-show=".show_2" class="show-me">Show</td>
  </tr>
  
    <tr class="hidden show_2">
    <td colspan=99>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Mobile number</th>
          <th>Provider</th>
          <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
          <td>999 999 999</td>
          <td>XYZ</td>
          <td>1274</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Paul</td>
    <td>Koel</td>
    <td>22.07.1999</td>
    <td>England</td>
    <td data-show=".show_3" class="show-me">Show</td>
  </tr>
  
    <tr class="hidden show_3">
    <td colspan=99>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Mobile number</th>
          <th>Provider</th>
          <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
          <td>999 999 999</td>
          <td>XYZ</td>
          <td>1274</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>888 888 888</td>
          <td>XYZ</td>
          <td>1111</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ha6gd53z/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slideUp()` & `slideDown()` wont work with `display: table`. So wrap `table` with  `div` (`display: block`)

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/r83dkep4/)**

Comment: Okay, that does seem to work. But is there any workaround for the weird "jumping" row under the one being expanded? Right after you expand the nested table it jumps a little bit and when the collapsing is almost done it again jumps up.

Comment: @popcorn That's because of padding `td[colspan="99"]` element. Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/r83dkep4/3/). If you need add padding to `div` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change display:none to display:inline-block for the "hidden" class.
I have updated fiddle.

Comment: where is fiddle ?